# Slow performance on DataTable foreach DataColum in C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, foreach, datatable

Between one version of our software and emerging beta, there is a significant delay in a method that loops over all the DataColumns in a DataTable (which is also within a loop over all the rows).

Here's the (simplified, but logically complete) code, which is the same for both versions:

```
Stopwatch foretimer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
foreach (DataColumn dc in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
{
    Stopwatch foreinnertimer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    RenderProfile.addProfile("Rows.StandardCellContents.foreEachColumn-Qty", 1);

    if (renderColumn(dc))
    {
        Stopwatch trtimer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        temp = TokenReplacement.replaceNonCachedTokens(temp, rsa, dc, dr);
        RenderProfile.add("Rows.StandardCellContents.replaceCellTokens", trtimer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        RenderProfile.add("Rows.StandardCellContents.replaceCellTokens-Qty", 1);

        RenderProfile.add("Rows.StandardCellContents.foreEachColumn-inner", foreinnertimer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
    RenderProfile.add("Rows.StandardCellContents.foreEachColumn-inner-ALL", foreinnertimer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
RenderProfile.add("Rows.StandardCellContents.foreEachColumn", foretimer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

(there are some changes to the underlying code in `TokenReplacement.replaceNonCachedTokens`, but it doesn't manifest significantly different profile times)

**These examples are for the same input**, which has 1000 rows, and 24 columns, 19 of which get 'rendered'.

This produces these profile values on the old version:

```
 Rows-Qty:1000
 Rows.StandardCellContents.foreEachColumn-Qty:24000
 Rows.StandardCellContents.replaceCellTokens:14ms
 Rows.StandardCellContents.replaceCellTokens-Qty:19000
 Rows.StandardCellContents.foreEachColumn-inner:14ms
 Rows.StandardCellContents.foreEachColumn-inner-ALL:14ms
 Rows.StandardCellContents.foreEachColumn:2032ms
```

and these profile values on the new version:

```
 Rows-Qty:1000
 Rows.StandardCellContents.foreEachColumn-Qty:24000
 Rows.StandardCellContents.replaceCellTokens:59ms
 Rows.StandardCellContents.replaceCellTokens-Qty:19000
 Rows.StandardCellContents.foreEachColumn-inner:66ms
 Rows.StandardCellContents.foreEachColumn-inner-ALL:67ms
 Rows.StandardCellContents.foreEachColumn:9174ms
```

**How can this be??**  It seems unfortunate that, even in the old (faster) version, the iteration over the DataColumns alone (`Rows.StandardCellContents.foreEachColumn`) is ~2 seconds, but what is absolutely bizarre to me is that the new version is consistently +7-8 seconds!!

They're both running on the same version of .NET (4.0).  I cannot find anything in the updates we've made that alter the structure of the DataTable.. is there something related to the DataSet/DataTable that could slow down a `for each` loop over all the columns??

Any guidance or advice for how to analyze this further is much appreciated.

Comment: @mjwills I don't *think* that there's code you're not seeing involved.. I guess you have to take my word that the 2 datatables involved have the same number of rows, and same columns, and the same data in all those cells.. but i assure you they do.  With simply the code that i've shown, isn't it clear that the simple foreach iteration is taking 7 more seconds on the new version?  I guess i'm looking for any 'known performance gotchas' around the DataTable and DataColumn collection, or advice on how to dig further in.

Comment: The simple way to validate that it's the `foreach` would be to time the `foreach` without doing anything in the loop -- comment the code like `renderColumn` and `TokenReplacement.replaceNonCachedTokens`.

Comment: @ilasno Are you able to profile you application with some of performance profiling tools, for example, with [`dotTrace JetBrains`](https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/). If you are it will be helpful to see performance snapshot. Even if you don't have a license for `dotTrace` you can download it and use trial version for 30 days.

Comment: What does ```renderColumn()``` do?  Could it be different than the old version?

Comment: Well i feel sheepish.. i thought that the strategic placement of my timers and time-recording statements was placing blame squarely on the actual iteration, but that appears to be a false assumption.  I'm still not sure why the ```Rows.StandardCellContents.foreEachColumn-inner-ALL``` doesn't show more time, since it should be summing the time for each iteration.. but when i comment out ALL the code within the ```foreach```, the slow performance goes away.  I'm digging deeper, thanks for all who gave me some time.  @HereticMonkey if you want to add your comment as an answer, i'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this doesn't really answer the question, but to diagnose whether the problem is indeed the iteration and not somewhere else, I would comment all of the code except the iteration:

```
Stopwatch foretimer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
foreach (DataColumn dc in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
{
    Stopwatch foreinnertimer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    RenderProfile.addProfile("Rows.StandardCellContents.foreEachColumn-Qty", 1);

    //if (renderColumn(dc))
    {
        //Stopwatch trtimer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        //temp = TokenReplacement.replaceNonCachedTokens(temp, rsa, dc, dr);
        //RenderProfile.add("Rows.StandardCellContents.replaceCellTokens", trtimer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        //RenderProfile.add("Rows.StandardCellContents.replaceCellTokens-Qty", 1);

        RenderProfile.add("Rows.StandardCellContents.foreEachColumn-inner", foreinnertimer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
    RenderProfile.add("Rows.StandardCellContents.foreEachColumn-inner-ALL", foreinnertimer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
RenderProfile.add("Rows.StandardCellContents.foreEachColumn", foretimer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

This will limit what's being timed to the `foreach` (and the hopefully negligible overhead of the `Stopwatch` and `RenderProfile` statements).

I'm guessing there's something in `renderColumn` or `TokenReplacement` that changed between the two versions (not necessarily in your code -- could be in framework code, although a performance regression of that magnitude would be unusual).